# Apple MacBook air is stuck on log in loading screen

Tags: disk-utility

I am running mojave os, When I enter password to log in, the loading bar start to fill up but it never get log in. Even if it completes 100%, it stucks there. I tried with safe mode same issue happened. 
Then i tried with recovery mode, the apple logo appears with loading bar but it never make it to the disc utility screen. It get stuck on the apple screen. After that i tried cmd + opt + r for over internet recovery, it downloaded, but after that the apple screen appears and stuck there.

After that i ran diagnosis but there was no issues found. I don’t know what exactly the problem is and what is the solution for this. I can’t make it to the disc utility or log in to mac. 
If anyone can help I will be really glad. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Anything attached to the USB or Thunderbolt ports? I’ve seen that happen when a HD or improperly formatted USB stick isn’t able to mount.

Comment: Yes I tried that! But didn’t work.

Comment: The next thing to try is resetting the SMC. Different procedures depending on model. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295